# Strange experience in my laptop of certain keys not working

Tags: laptop, keyboard, hardware-failure, hp-elitebook, keystrokes

I actually asked this in HP support forums and their Customer Service Rep., but no one knows whats going on.So, I am throwing open this question here , esp. so that some Geek Squad guy, who has seen this before can give an insight into what could be happening.
Problem - "b", "n", Caps, "-", ">" (right cursor), "END" group of keys stop working abruptly.

This is a Elitebook 8460p under warranty. Neither me nor the tech.  field support is able to figure out what's going. At the outset  - If you feel ANY of the above letters missing in the write up, its because I did not, "toggle invoke"  my virtual keyboard. I just had the keyboard changed and this problem still persists in fact it has gotten more persistent  after the new keyboard change .
Earlier  -it was more fluctuant than it is now. My options are to change keyboard, system-board or both. Keyboard change did  not help so far. Before I try the system board change I wanted to throw open this problem. I read SIMILAR posts in previous threads  on HP support - but  NONE of them have been able to identity  the root cause -they are in fact all Incomplete, where the last post from the asker still shows no resolution. Did anyone run into the problem and figure out where it hits (software or hardware?). All the diagnostic tests are normal.

I downgraded the keyboard driver but the problem still persists .My best hunch on this is that, one specific  strand of connection from the keyboard to the system board  isn't working  & that maps to this group of keys .It maybe that the corresponding  system board connector for this is not working.  A hardware key-map document ( which circuit strand maps to which keys ) will confirm this.  I have a dual boot environment with Ubuntu &  when the problem is present in Windows its also present in Ubuntu. USB keyboard works just fine.

Another observation is that once these set of keys are dead,  the  keys B or N  (think most times it is B) brings  back alive this  dead bunch, like  50% times (for the rest - I am stuck and have to use a work around).

Comment: intermitten problems like these are more often than not hardware related, especially if pressing certain areas bring it back to life. software is fairly easy to test by booting from a USB live image and doing a bios update. Hope that helps a little.

Comment: BIOS is up to date. When it fails - it fails  OS regardless - in Linux and windows

Comment: In that case it is most likely a hardware issue. Never had the problem on my 4 year old 8540W so cant draw anything from that.

Comment: Change your keyboard has helped and it hasn't shown up after that

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but for those searching for this issue:

This sounds like it's shorting out or not receiving enough power from the cable. I'm inclined to agree with you that it's the connection, given that it's also broken when booted into Ubuntu and a USB keyboard working. It's pointing to the OS and BIOS being able to register the keys fine on *a* keyboard, it's just any keyboard connected to *this* cable doesn't work.

However, the fact that it's intermittent points to it not being a broken connection in the wire and more likely a voltage/voltage flow issue. Check the capacitors around the keyboard connection on the board, but if it's under warranty, just have them replace the board entirely.

Answer (score 1):

The chip u23, smc 1098 is bad as just happened here. It's 50% - comes and goes.

Symptoms:

- 2 keyboards fail (1 is new).
- BIOS F60 with Intel firmware (ME) fresh (oct 2012 release) and USB works (always).
- Win10 virtual keyboard works (on the screen) always and during the failure.

Conclusion is: ESD damaged U23 or the connector is bad.

I've cleaned mine with alcohol (carefully) and looked for cracks on that same connector, and even put side stress on it when the keys fail and when not failing.
that is all one can do..

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. If you have a new question please [ask your own question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) (referencing this one for context if it helps).